# Is there any way to convert JSONP format to JSON?

Tags: android, jsonp

I am trying to parse a response from server and i am new to this topic, Unfortunately it is in JSONP format. I don't know how to parse JSONP format, when i tried with JSON Parser it is returning null value. 
Can anyone please help me in doing this...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is just JSON wrapped in a JavaScript function call.  For instance, something like:

```
callback({"status":"success", "someVar":1});
```

So you have a couple of options.  If you are using a `WebView` you can define a function called `callback` in JavaScript and then just call `eval()` on the JSONP data.  This will invoke the `callback` function, passing it the parsed JSON object (the `eval()` does the parsing for you).

Or, if you have the JSONP string in your Java code, the simplest option is probably to extract out the JSON substring, like:

```
String json = jsonp.substring(jsonp.indexOf("(") + 1, jsonp.lastIndexOf(")"));
```

That will strip off `callback(` and `);`, leaving you with just `{"status":"success", "someVar":1}`, which should then parse with any standard JSON parser.

Comment: i am not using webview, iam using this for login purpose, so what i did is, if the respone is not null, then user goes into the next screen, i used json parser so i am getting parsing error. can you give me an example to do this..

Comment: Yes, use the second example above, the one with the `substring()` calls.  Then just do `JSONValue.parse(json)`, or whatever your JSON parser's equivalent is.  Runnable example:  http://ideone.com/5v3z6

Comment: sorry.. i am new to this topic.. when i'm parsing with JSON parser, it showing null, so how can i do that? can u please post me the complete code..

Comment: I want to ask, isn`t there a way to wrap the json on the way it is served so json file is not jsonp but eventually becomes when served by the script?
[ {"name":"foo", "id":1} ] will be original and when loaded to dom it will be wrapped into foo() for example?

Comment: This fails when the callback is prefixed with a JSONP hijack buster, such as `while(1);` or `for(;;;);`, unfortunately.