# Cannot read jsonp output

Tags: android

**Android Code**

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://192.168.1.104/Ceylon_Steel/service/getCategoriesAndItems");
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
                JSONObject posts = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                JSONArray jArray = posts.getJSONArray("categories");
                Log.i("Tag", jArray.toString());
```

**Json**

```
categories_and_items({
    categories: [
        {
            id: "c2",
            item: [
                {
                    itemId: "9",
                    itemCode: "FG039062",
                    description: "E1-LINER 38x26-R: NAKAYAMA NCF-2B IMPACT CHUSHER",
                    price: "0.00",
                    quantity: "100000"
                },

            ]
        },

    ]
})
```

Here I tried Above code to retrieve data from json and print the it on the log but whwn try that i get following error.

```
12-06 10:11:38.578: W/System.err(3695): org.json.JSONException: Value categories_and_items of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: This is not valid JSON string. You can check here : http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: categories_and_items(....) you are appending this or you are getting this from server...???

Comment: I take it from server

Comment: You need to change your response. Its not possible to parse as its invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON response is invalid. Its should always starts with `{...}` brackets not with `(..)` brackets.

If possible change your response by removing `(..)` brackets as below :

```
categories_and_items{
    categories: [
        {
            id: "c2",
            item: [
                {
                    itemId: "9",
                    itemCode: "FG039062",
                    description: "E1-LINER 38x26-R: NAKAYAMA NCF-2B IMPACT CHUSHER",
                    price: "0.00",
                    quantity: "100000"
                },

            ]
        },

    ]
}
```

Comment: Actually i can take that value json from server using Jquery without giving any error

Comment: You may be getting the value but you will not be able to parse it using the JSONObject as its not valid JSON format actually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the json is valid.

what is

```
categories_and_items( ... )
```

Comment: Actuuly it is a jsnop .categories_and_items is Call back name

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275205/is-there-any-way-to-convert-jsonp-format-to-json