# JSONP- java String cannot be converted to JSONObject (Android)

Tags: java, android, json

That's my code:

```
String json =  request.excutePost("http://192.168.1.42:3000/login_client",urlParameters);
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

The logCat display me the next error:

> org.json.JSONException: Value
>   {"login_client":"NEW_PASSWORD","token":"2de374f454699aa6fe895c56bc3a111b33f28b72888aec1f5faa77977e232828"}
>   of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

that's the executePost function:

```
public String excutePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {

        //Create connection
        URL url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.close();
        //Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // or StringBuffer if not Java 5+
        String line;

        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        //respuesta = response.toString().replaceAll("\"",);
        Log.e("RESPONSE",response.toString());
        return response.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of your  "json" string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267910/jsonexception-value-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject)

Comment: Could you show body of excutePost

Comment: the json values is : 
{"login_client":"NEW_PASSWORD","token":"2de374f454699aa6fe895c56bc3a111b33f28b72888aec1f5faa77977e232828"}
I've test it in jsonlint and is ok

Comment: the json is a JSONP

Comment: your JSON value is valid how could this be possible. print the value in logcat and **see carefully i guess you are having some unnecessary characters in your response**

Comment: look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10275259/624069)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that your string has not been formatted well to convert. it should be some thing like this:

```
"{\"login_client\":\"NEW_PASSWORD\",\"token\":\"2de374f454699aa6fe895c56bc3a111b33f28b72888aec1f5faa77977e232828\"} "
```

try the code bellow:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject

String json =  request.excutePost("http://192.168.1.42:3000/login_client",urlParameters);
JSONObject obj = new JSONParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
```

for more information take a look at this question :
[How to convert String to JSONObject in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java)

Comment: which kind of package are you using? this will work with org.json

Comment: I'm using org.json but JsonParser doesn't appear

Comment: it is case sensitive you should use "JSONParser" i will edit my answer .

Comment: I've found the solution in the reprecente that you give me, I must use Gson from com.google.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
String json =  new String(request.excutePost("http://192.168.1.42:3000/login_client",urlParameters));
Log.e("Response",""+json);
```

Comment: that's the response:
"{\"login_client\":\"NEW_PASSWORD\",\"token\":\"2de374f454699aa6fe895c56bc3a111b33f28b72888aec1f5faa77977e232828\"}"